# Setting Values in Pandas Dataframe Based on Condition in Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am looking to update the values in a pandas series that satisfy a certain condition and take the corresponding value from another column.

Specifically, I want to look at the `subcluster` column and if the value equals 1, I want the record to update to the corresponding value in the `cluster` column.

For example:

| Cluster | Subcluster |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

Should result in this

| Cluster | Subcluster |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |

I've been trying to use apply and a lambda function, but can't seem to get it to work properly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case try `mask`

```
df.Subcluster.mask(lambda x : x==1, df.Cluster,inplace=True)
df
Out[12]: 
   Cluster  Subcluster
0        3           3
1        3           2
2        3           3
3        3           4
4        4           4
5        4           2
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.Subcluster==1,'Subcluster'] = df['Cluster']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Subcluster'] = np.where(df['Subcluster'].eq(1), df['Cluster'], df['Subcluster'])
```

Output:

```
    Cluster  Subcluster
0         3           3
1         3           2
2         3           3
3         3           4
4         4           4
5         4           2
```

Answer (score 0):

Really all you need here is to use .loc with a mask (you don't actually need to create the mask, you could apply a mask inline)

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster':np.random.randint(0,10,10)
                    ,'subcluster':np.random.randint(0,3,10)}
                 )
df.to_clipboard(sep=',')
```

`df` at this point

```
,cluster,subcluster
0,8,0
1,5,2
2,6,2
3,6,1
4,8,0
5,1,1
6,0,0
7,6,0
8,1,0
9,3,1
```

create and apply the mask (you could do this all in one line)

```py
mask = df.subcluster == 1
df.loc[mask,'subcluster'] = df.loc[mask,'cluster']
df.to_clipboard(sep=',')
```

final output:

```
,cluster,subcluster
0,8,0
1,5,2
2,6,2
3,6,6
4,8,0
5,1,1
6,0,0
7,6,0
8,1,0
9,3,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the lambda you couldn't write. In lamba, `x` corresponds to the index, so you can use that to refer a specific row in a column.

```
df['Subcluster'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Cluster'] if x['Subcluster'] == 1 else x['Subcluster'], axis = 1)
```

And the output:

```
    Cluster Subcluster
0   3       3
1   3       2
2   3       3
3   3       4
4   4       4
5   4       2
```